# Why was my comment deleted without explanation or a discernible good reason?

Tags: discussion

In this question [competetive viable or junk?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47315/competetive-viable-or-junk) I left a comment explaining why the question was a bad match for this SE, and I want to think it was constructive criticism, nothing remotely delete-worthy IMHO. It got deleted along with a string of less helpful comments. I would like to know why my comment got deleted.

This is not the first time a comment of mine was deleted that was IMO perfectly fine. Comment deletion should be a lot more transparent so people can learn what got it deleted, or to appeal the decision.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't post a comment on that question. You posted a comment on [this nearly identical deleted question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47314/what-do-you-think-about-this-janky-combo). Your comment there was only deleted because the entire post was deleted.